# How to wait for Http requests in a loop to finish execution in order to proceed with some dependent piece of code?

Tags: http, promise, angular7

I need to make a API call(Main API call) which depends on the result of several other API calls(Child calls) but i am unable to do the desireful since the result of Child calls will not be availble at the time i make the Main api call due to asynchronous execution.

Here is my code (what i have been trying)-

Http Service Function -

```
async fetchShift(shiftName: string): Promise<any> {

const res = await this.httpClient.get(this.systemConfig.UIBACKEND_API_URL + '/api/v1/shift/find/' + shiftName).toPromise();
return res;
}
```

Intermediate Function -

```
async formAssociateProduct(sheetAllRows): Promise<any> {

var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  for (let i: number = 0; i < sheetAllRows.length; i++) {
    //Child api calls
    this.fetchShift("A").then(data => {
      this.listOfAssociatedProduct.push(data);
    });
  }
  resolve();
});
return promise;

}
```

Caller Function-

```
upload(event) {
console.log(event);
var me = this;
var reader = new FileReader();
var file = event.target.files[0];
reader.onload = function (event) {
  var workbook = XLSX.read(event.target.result, {
    type: 'binary'
  });

  var sheetAllRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"]);
   me.formAssociateProduct(sheetAllRows).then(
    data => {
      //Main Api Call
      me.httpClient.post(me.systemConfig.UIBACKEND_API_URL + '/api/v1/products/upload', me.listOfAssociatedProduct).subscribe(data => {

      });
    }
  );  };

reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

I find the list empty in the then() callback that is required to make the Main api call. Please help.

Comment: `formAssociateProduct` is an asyncFunction but it doesn't `await this.fetchShift("A")...`

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problems here.  Here's a summary of the changes/comments:

1. In `formAssociateProduct()`, you aren't waiting for all the asynchronous calls to be done before resolving the returned promise.  I'd suggest using `Promise.all()` to track when they are all done.  And, there's no benefit from having the function `async` since you aren't using `await`.  You can just return a promise directly.  When doing async processing on an array, it's often cleaner to use `.map()` and get an array of promises which you can then feed to `Promise.all()` to know when they are all done.
2. `fetchShift()` looks like it would work as it was, but again, there's no reason for it to be tagged `async`, you can just return the promise directly.
3. In `upload()`, the logic looks like it was mostly correct.  I switched to an arrow function for a callback so you can use `this` directly instead of `me`.  Also, it looks like this function needs error handling on the `reader`, on the call to `formAssociateProduct()` and on the main API call.
4. It looks like you're mixing promises and a callback from `.subscribe()` at the lowest level of `upload()`.  That does not typically work well because it's hard to propogate completion, results and errors back to the caller.  I don't know those particular APIs or know exactly  what you're trying to accomplish there to know exactly what to suggest.

Here's the fixed up code:

```
fetchShift(shiftName: string): Promise < any > {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.systemConfig.UIBACKEND_API_URL + '/api/v1/shift/find/' + shiftName).toPromise();
}

// call fetchShift on all the sheet rows
formAssociateProduct(sheetAllRows): Promise < any > {
    return Promise.all(sheetAllRows.map(row => {
        return this.fetchShift("A");
    })).then(results => {
        this.listOfAssociatedProduct = results;
    });
}

upload(event) {
    console.log(event);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    reader.onload = (event) => {
        var workbook = XLSX.read(event.target.result, {
            type: 'binary'
        });

        var sheetAllRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"]);
        // need lots of error handling here
        this.formAssociateProduct(sheetAllRows).then(data => {
            //Main Api Call
            return this.httpClient.post(me.systemConfig.UIBACKEND_API_URL + '/api/v1/products/upload',
                this.listOfAssociatedProduct).subscribe(data => {
                // some code here
            });
        });
    }
    // start reading the file
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

Comment: @Buddha - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.